# Cannot run rspec with filter tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, zsh

I have spec

```
RSpec.describe SearchFlight::Jet::SearchFlightRequest do
  describe 'send search ticket request to Jetstar website', http_request: true do
    context 'search ticket round trip successfully' do
      # initialize
      it 'return status 200' do
        # my expects here ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run rspec on my iterm, it couldn't run

```
bundle exec rspec -t ~http_request
zsh: no such user or named directory: http_request
```

Maybe it related to zsh command line ([issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3957)). I try to remove zsh from my iTerms 2 but it's not success. Any alternative shell for Rails dev ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like

```
rspec --tag "~http_request"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle exec rspec --tag ~http_request
```

Comment: no, still error: bundle exec rspec --tag ~http_request
zsh: no such user or named directory: http_request

Answer (score 0):

In zsh the ~name syntax is expanded to /folder/of/name/user. You can bypass this behavior by adding noglob at the beginning of the command: noglob rspec.... You can also alias the rspec command so that you don't have to put write that every time: alias rspec='noglob rspec '.

Comment: it didn't work. it still run all spec files after I added to .rspec file

Comment: @LeoLe You try --tag instead -t ?

Comment: no, still error: bundle exec rspec --tag ~http_request
zsh: no such user or named directory: http_request

Comment: You use oh-my-zsh?

Comment: same result ! noglob rspec -t ~ http_request zsh: no such user or named directory: http_request

Comment: Temporarily, change to bash and try again. If works your problem is zsh! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but `~http_request` has been recognized as the home folder of user "http_request".

You can escape `~` by using `\~`

```
bundle exec rspec -t \~http_request
```

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/442394/why-does-cd-k-tab-expands-to-cd-kernoops-when-i-already-have-a-folder-name#